# My PHP array somehow doesn't see my array as an array

Tags: php

Okay, I've narrowed this down to one key function.

It seems impossible, but every time I've "echo"ed it, this function always says that the variable array I'm using to store my data is no longer an array.

**Offending Code**

```
private function do_display_message_details()
{
  $m_message_values = '';
  $m_address = APP_ROOT_PATH;

  if ($this->c_arr_stored_message_data)
  {
    echo "I AM AN ARRAY";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "I AM NOT AN ARRAY";
  }


  $m_message_name = $this->c_arr_stored_message_data['message-name'];
  $m_arr_stored_message_data = $this->c_arr_stored_message_data['message-retrieved-data'];

  foreach((array)$m_arr_stored_message_data as $m_message_value)
  {
    $m_message_row = explode(',', $m_message_value);
    $m_message_values .= '<tr>';
    $m_message_values .= '<td>' . $m_message_row[0] . '</td>';
    $m_message_values .= '<td>' . $m_message_row[1] . '</td>';
    $m_message_values .= '<td>' . $m_message_row[2] . '</td>';
    $m_message_values .= '</tr>';
  }

  $this->c_html_page_content = <<< VIEWSTOREDMESSAGEDATA
    <div id="lg-form-container">
      <h2>Message name: $m_message_name</h3>
      <h3>Message Data</h3>
      <table border="1">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Message Values</th>
          </tr>
          $m_message_values
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br />

      <form method="post" action="$m_address">
        <label for="anothergo">Another Message?</label>
        <button name="feature" value="display_message_data">Review Stored Message Data</button>
      </form>
    </div>
VIEWSTOREDMESSAGEDATA;
}
```

**Constructor to show you it is set up as an array**

```
    private $c_arr_stored_message_data;
    private $c_error_message;
    private $c_page_content;

// ~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->c_arr_stored_message_data = array();
        $this->c_error_message = '';
        $this->c_page_content = '';
    }
```

But, if you try it on a different function, it works.

**Trial Code That Works!**

```
// ~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*
    public function set_stored_message_data($p_arr_stored_message_data)
    {
        $this->c_arr_stored_message_data = $p_arr_stored_message_data;
       if ($this->c_arr_stored_message_data)
       {
         echo "I AM AN ARRAY";
       }
       else
       {
         echo "I AM NOT AN ARRAY";
       }
    }
```

Comment: What's not working? The display of results in HTML, or are you getting any error messages? :-)

Comment: @ninetwozero The display. There's no error messages, but there's nothing being displayed either

Comment: A non-question related suggestion, name your variables and functions in a non-self-absorving way , it will be easier for everyone trying to help you out.

Comment: @JoelHernandez Wish it were that easy. 
For this work, I have to submit it in Hungarian Notation, that means "$m" variables are method variables, "$c" variables are class variables; then "arr" are array variables, "obj" are object variables, etc. It's annoying, but thems the rules

Comment: Have you done any debugging, or did you just throw your hands in the air and say "it's not working"?

Comment: @Boann Yeah. I've tried debugging. The problem is, it doesn't stop at the breakpoints, so I can't see the debug screen. Also: Who gave me negative votes? I've now got 2 reputation... Thanks [/Sarc]

Comment: @Raisus So, of the code you've posted, you have no idea which methods are actually getting run, whether the problem is in one of them or somewhere else, whether the database credentials are correct or not, whether query is executing or not, or whether you're simply losing the data somewhere in that mess of badly named methods, and now you expect someone else to tell you what's wrong because you're incapable of even using echo statements to debug it? That's why you're getting downvotes.

Comment: @Boann I don't expect someone to tell me what's wrong. I am asking if someone would be kind enough to help me. There's a difference, buddy. You don't have to supply your advice any more than I have to put up with you leaving it. Go suck a lemon

Comment: UPDATE: Made headway into narrowing down the offending piece of code. See Topic for Details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "I AM AN ARRAY" checks don't work quite as you think:

```
$x = array();
if ($x) {
    echo 'I AM AN ARRAY';
} else {
    echo 'I AM NOT AN ARRAY';
}
```

That prints out 'I AM NOT AN ARRAY', as [an empty array evaluates to false in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). You can use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to see exactly what content your variables have.

You have a variable named `$c_page_content` but later you refer to `$c_html_page_content`. Perhaps a mistake?

If the "messages" can contain user-supplied text, then there are XSS vulnerabilities in your code. It is essential to use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to render text in HTML. For example, if `$m_message_row[0]` is text, you must write `'<td>' . htmlspecialchars($m_message_row[0]) . '</td>'`. Ditto for any other values that are not supposed to contain HTML markup that are written to HTML.

Your main issue, that the data is apparently not being stored in your `c_arr_stored_message_data` variable, is not possible to reproduce without seeing the connecting code that calls `set_stored_message_data` and `do_display_message_details`. All I can suggest is that you make sure you're calling them in the right order on the same instance of the same class.

Comment: Thanks for offerring some help, I got it sorted anyway. It was a rouge assignment operator, basically I had an "If" statement that had one equals sign on it, I never gave it a second thought, but as soon as I added a second equals sign, the issue went away and my data began showing.